# Mi StoredProcedure funciona localmente en mi maquina pero cuando lo ejecuto el un server no funciona

Tags: sql-server, archivo, stored-procedure, subida-de-archivos

Ejecuto este stored procedure desde mi computadora, donde estoy desarrollando, y funciona correctamente; pero cuando ejecuto ese sp directo en el servidor de producción, simplemente no lo hace; en específico, si hace el *update* de los campos, pero no guarda en la base de datos el archivo que le estoy adjuntando.

Sin embargo en mi máquina local si lo hace. ¿Qué me sugieren que pueda ser el error?

```
USE [xxxxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_AcuseAR]    Script Date: 26/02/2024 02:43:44 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_AcuseAR]
(
@id_atencion int ,
@acuse image ,
@nombreacuse varchar(max) 
)
as
begin
update Tbl_xxx
set Acuse=@acuse,
NombreAcuse=@nombreacuse
where 
Id_Atencion=@id_atencion
end
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! rutas? permisos? falta mucha info como para ayudarte

Comment: Per dónde estas pasando un archivo? el SP solo está haciendo el update.

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas _archivo_? En el código que publicaste no se ve que se procese ningún tipo de archivo.